# gitlab error: No such file or directory,what is the wrong

Tags: git, gitlab

```
bash: /home/git/gitlab/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell: No such file or directory,what is the problem.
```

when I clone the gitlab repo, I get the error . Do I  had  wrong configuration ?

Comment: If you run `ls -lrt /home/git/gitlab/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell` is the application `gitlab-shell` found?

Comment: no,the gitlab-shell's real path is "/home/git/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell",so i think i must had  error setting. but i don't know where it is

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your path you seems to be running something from the wrong path...

"/home/git/gitlab/apps/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell"

Gitlab is there twice and the path doesn't make sense. Try this instead:

"/home/git/gitlab/gitlab-shell/bin/gitlab-shell"

If this doesn't change anything, then make sure you cloned gitlab-shell itself too: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#toc_6 (read the installation instruction)